# Android Development: Nested Context Menus?

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

Is it possible to have nested context menus? I am working on an app which needs to provide the users with various functionality, and after much thought I came to the conclusion that using a context menu would be quite advantageous (would allow me to clean up my screen by getting rid of a few spinners etc)

However I was wondering if its even possible to have a context menu pop up, and then on the item select present the user with even more choices.

Something along these lines:

```
Context Menu 1 
 -> Change Font Color (on select generate context menu 2)
    ->Red
    ->Green
 -> Change Background Color (on select generate context menu 3)
    ->Red
    ->Green
```

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: Thought I would ask to see if its even possible first rather than mess around with something that might never work when I have other parts of the app to be working on.

Comment: I can see the reason, but it's a good practice to try things first - and ask for help when they don't work.

Comment: I take it by your response it is possible in some fashion then? lol

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? Do you what to do this in xml or Java? If you are using eclipse you could just create a menu in your "menu" folder which contains an xml file and then use their "manager" to create a sub menu.

Here's an example menu named game_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

To create submenu you have to "nest `<menu>` elements"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Go to Defining a Menu in XML